# Add background image to all UITableViewCell

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

I used willDisplayCell delegate method to show a custom background image to a UITableViewCell.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
           willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell 
           forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static UIImage* bgImage = nil;
    if (bgImage == nil) {
        bgImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"myImage.png"];
    }
    cell.backgroundView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:bgImage];
}
```

When I run the app in the simulator, the background only for the cells that are drawn are changed, is there a way to change all cells' background?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have worked this code.It's working good .you can try this code.

```
 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:@"Cell"] autorelease];



        UIImageView *cellBackView=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 100)];
        cellBackView.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];


            cellBackView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"list.png"];



        cell.backgroundView = cellBackView;
        cell.selectionStyle=UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;




    return cell;



}
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried that but still only the drawn cells' background is changing the rest are still plain white.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the backgroundView property in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method that creates the cell:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

   UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

   if (!cell)
   {
       cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
   }

   cell.backgroundView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:...];

   return cell;
}
```

Comment: You could allocate the image view once, store it in your data provider, and then give the same object to all cells, rather than allocating a new one for each cell.

Comment: But it still setting the background only for the drawn cells. I have 2 cells with background and the rest of the cells are still white.

Comment: Simply call [tableView reloadData] to redraw all cells.

Comment: Call it after I set the backgroundView in cellForRowAtIndexPath? It still the same. Thanks!